# How to give a new user permissions to call sudo without a prompt for sudo password?

Tags: permissions, sudo, users, amazon-ec2

I am setting up a server in Amazon EC2. I created an image from Amazon's provided images of Ubuntu x64 12 LTS. My goal is to set up a secure svn server there, where access is only possible by IP address, SSH and certificates. I also need to migrate existing public keys from an old server.

Having played with permissions I managed to add another user account, but somehow locked myself (`ubuntu`) out of the server. Remote `root` log in is disabled, and I locked `ubuntu` user. Ooops.

This is why I would like to create a temporary user account, say `FOO`. If I lock it out, I still have `ubuntu`. I would like this user to have the same privileges as `ubuntu`, i.e. I want to do something like

```
sudo apt-get install subversion
```

**Problem**

When I created a new user and sshed to the server, the server always asked me for sudo password, when I called anything starting from `sudo`

**Question**

How to add a new user with the same privileges as `ubuntu`, so I can call `sudo ...` without being prompted with a sudo password?

This is what I have done so far:

```
# add user
sudo useradd -m -G ubuntu,adm,dialout,dip,plugdev,netdev,admin FOO

# add public key for ssh
sudo -s
cd /home/FOO
mkdir .ssh
cd .ssh
nano authorized_keys

    Generate certificate in PuttyGen
    Add public key to authorized_keys

#set permissions for ssh to work
chown -R FOO /home/FOO/.ssh
chgrp -R FOO /home/FOO/.ssh
chmod 0755 /home/FOO
chmod 755  /home/FOO/.ssh
chmod 644  /home/FOO/.ssh/authorized_keys

#add FOO to sudoers
sudo usermod -aG sudo FOO

##check permissions
ls -lha /home/FOO
ls -lha /home/FOO/.ssh
```

Answer (score 3):

That's easy. I'll refer to another answer of mine and give the gist for your case. My other answer was: [When Ubuntu asks for an admin user's password, how does it decide which administrative user to ask for?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/87509/#250077)

The gist is to edit `/etc/sudoers` and add a `Cmnd_Alias` (say `PRIVCMDS`) for the command you want to allow and then something like this in `sudoers`:

```
%ubuntu ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:PRIVCMDS
```

But please read through my complete answer to the other question.

The above is for the system group named `ubuntu`. If you wanted the same for the user named `ubuntu` it would read:

```
ubuntu ALL=(root) NOPASSWD:PRIVCMDS
```